# PHP json вывод данных

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, json

Всем привет! помогите вывести метку на карту.

Есть бд, вывести все метки получается, отображаются все метки на карте данные берутся из бд,
при выборе определенной страницы или при ее редактировании есть карта и мне нужно вывести текущую метку на текущей странице, заменив данные центра карты
как вывести данную метку с текущей страницы, подскажите пожалуйста

при таком коде все метки отображаются

Js карт

```
    var myMap, myCollection;

    ymaps.ready(init);


  function init () {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [53.195831, 50.104566],
        zoom: 13.31
        }, {
            balloonMaxWidth: 300
            });


    myMap.controls
        .add('zoomControl');
        myMap.controls.add('typeSelector')  ;







    var MyBalloonContentLayoutClass = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<strong>$[properties.name]</strong>' +
    '<p>$[properties.description]</p>'
    );

    $.getJSON("metki.php",
function(json){
for (i = 0; i < json.markers.length; i++) {

var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([json.markers[i].lat,json.markers[i].lon], {
            name: json.markers[i].icontext,
            description: json.markers[i].balloontext,
            hintContent: json.markers[i].hinttext
            },{
                balloonContentLayout: MyBalloonContentLayoutClass,
                preset: json.markers[i].styleplacemark
            });

  // Добавляем метку на карту
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
}


});}
```

содержимое файла metki.php подгружаемого с js

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
while ($mar = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$json =  array(icontext=>$mar['title'], hinttext=>$mar['title'], balloontext=>$mar['mini_description'], styleplacemark=>$mar['stylePlacemark'], lat=>$mar['lat'], lon=>$mar['lon']);
$markers[] = $json;
}

}
$points = array(markers=>$markers);

echo json_encode($points);

}


?>
```

например я открыл для изменения страницу продукта id 27, нужно чтобы карта подгрузилаась только с одной меткой и данными из бд продукта с id27 в бд хранятся широта и долгота в столбцах lat lon. чтобы центр карты встал на данную метку, как реализовать такое?

пробовал поменять в metki.php строку чтобы просто хоть вывести метку одну но получаю ошибку в консоле

эту строку

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products");
```

менял на

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id'",$link);
```

но не выходит =(

было бы хорошо если бы было как тут

https://snipp.ru/view/142 реализовано но не получается подкл PDO не сталкивался
там как раз было бы хорошо на странице редактирование в подвале оставить код где координаты центра менялись бы на точку с выбраной меткой ну и данные балуна конечно

Если убрать одинарные кавычки то получаю

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

если же поставлю

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE products_id=id",$link);
```

то получаю метку на выводит метку id 1 самую первую из бд хотя редактируется метка 27

пока не могу получить данные о текущей метки
открыл метку для редактирования id метки в бд 27
но не могу правильно отправить данные из бд c id 27 и получить нужный json ответ чтобы вставить координаты и вывести метку на карту ( только одну метку)
Если в теле php файла metkared.php
ставлю

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id'",$link);

    If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {

    $mar = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    {
        $json =  array(icontext=>$mar['title'], hinttext=>$mar['brand'], balloontext=>$mar['mini_description'], styleplacemark=>$mar['stylePlacemark'], lat=>$mar['lat'], lon=>$mar['lon']);
        $markers[] = $json;

    }$points = array(markers=>$markers);
    echo json_encode($points);
    }
}
```

то я получаю json с данными текущей страницы c id 27

но тогда ниже в теле metkared.php если писать js как вывести их если использовать тот же код js что и выше ясно дело что он не сможет ничего получить из `$.getJSON("metki.php"`

Comment: центр карты у вас явно в настройках задан `center: [53.195831, 50.104566]`